# Возведение в степень. Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Всем привет. Вопрос, как в **Kotlin** сделать возведение в степень? Пробовал через `Math.pow()`, выдаёт ошибку:

```
import java.math.*

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var cor: Double = 12.4
    Math.pow(cor)
}
```

Comment: Вы не указали, в какую степень вы хотите возвести число.

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.math/pow.html

Comment: в переменной cor, указано число, которое мне нужно возвести

Comment: Если выдает ошибку, то нужно читать её. Ошибки для того и выдаются, чтобы было понятно,  в чем проблема. Если не понятно, то текст ошибки нужно включать в вопрос.

Comment: var result =cor * cor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы вероятно хотели возвести во вторую степень и вывести результат:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    var cor: Double = 12.4
    val result = cor.pow(2.0)
    println("Result: ${result}")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
...
val x: Double = 1.0
val y:Double = 2.0
val z = x.pow(y)
println("{z}")
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Кому надо для Int (без учета степени 1):

```
private fun Int.pow(x: Int): Int = (2..x).fold(this) { r, _ -> r * this }
```